# Get Maximum Date for each month (T-SQL)

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with data given in the screen shot

.[image]

I need to take only those records which has maximum Snapshot_Date for each month.

I need my resultant dataset as below

[image]

How could i do this. I need your ideas.

I tried using

```
select * 
from table 
where Snapshot_Date = (select MAX(Snapshot_Date) 
                       from table 
                      where DATEPART(MONTH,Snapshot_Date)=11)
```

but i need to hardcode the month number here!!
Thanks for your time!!

Comment: you haven't shown any attempt....

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT Snapshot_Date, Quantity
FROM
    (
        SELECT  DATENAME(month, Snapshot_Date) MonthName, 
                Snapshot_Date, Quantity,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATENAME(month, Snapshot_Date)
                                    ORDER BY Snapshot_Date DESC) rn
        FROM    tableName
    ) a
WHERE rn = 1
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07467/5)

Sources

- [**DATENAME**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395(v=sql.90).aspx)
- [**OVER** Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)
- [**ROW_NUMBER()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your response. That gave an idea to use partition function.

Comment: did it satisfies your needs? :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I solved this by using partition function as below

`SELECT Snapshot_Date, Quantity
FROM ( 
  SELECT Snapshot_Date, Quantity, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(MONTH, '20000101', Snapshot_Date)
   ORDER BY Snapshot_Date desc)
  FROM table
) AS x
WHERE x.rn = 1
ORDER BY x.Snapshot_Date`